# PHP and MySQL, Using a foreign key to get data from another table where it originates from

Tags: php, sql

This question involves 3 tables that I have in PHPmyAdmin called:

- `tblShoots`
- `tblMemberOnShoot`
- `tblMember`

I need to run a query on a users dashboard which tells them, which photoshoots they have been to.The `tblmemberOnShoot` table is shown below, if I was to click on through an entry under `fldShootID` (which is a foreign key), it would take me to `tblShoots` which holds the shoot details, in there I need to pull out `fldShootLocation`.

[image: tblMemberOnShoot Table]

At the moment my query is shown below which doesn't entirely give the output needed, I need help with the join?

```
<?php 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblMembersOnShoot` WHERE `fldMemberID` = 1";

        $result = $conn -> query($query);

        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo $row['fldShootID']."<br>";

            } 
    ?>
```

Output on the page:
[image]

Comment: You need to join the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, a `JOIN` is the way to go. Here's what I'd suggest:

```
SELECT fldShootLocation FROM tblMember
LEFT JOIN tblMembersOnShoot
ON tblMembersOnShoot.fldMemberID = tblMember.fldMemberID
LEFT JOIN tblShoots
ON tblShoots.fldShootID = tblMembersOnShoot.fldShootID
WHERE tblMember.fldMemberID = 1
```

Comment: Hi @DanielG can I ask if I place ` symbols still around each reference to the fields or tables ?

Comment: @K.Haydock You can definitely put the symbol around field names and tables if you like (PHPMyAdmin will do it by default), but it's not required by MySQL.

Comment: Hi @DanielG I can't see where I've made the mistake, I've updated the code I'm no using....I'm getting the error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhotoClub/after-login.php:227 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhotoClub/after-login.php on line 227

Comment: You can make this query much cleaner with `USING()`

Comment: @K.Haydock Error checking but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` `ini_set('log_errors',1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @K.Haydock Try running the Query in PHPMyAdmin to confirm everything works correctly. That will spit out SQL specific errors.

Comment: Ahhhh @DanielG I for some reason called it tblShoot NOT tblShoots (rookie error), so it runs absolutely fine in mySql, I echoed out fldShootLocation and it works perfectly! I need to study how you've done this join so I can understand it :-) Thank you!! Have a lovely eve

Comment: @DanielG is there anyway I can look up and explain simply how these work as I don't quite understand how it's worked with the first line as `fldShootLocation` isn't held in `tblMember`, confused.com   :)

Comment: @K.Haydock I know you can run `EXPLAIN` on the query if you make it a view, but think of selecting `fldShootLocation` as actually selecting `tblShoot.fldShootLocation`. You can visualize a `JOIN` as tables getting pushed together and now you have access to all of the columns in each table as one big table. `JOIN` and `ON` is just a more efficient way of selecting multiple tables with `FROM` and `WHERE`.